# What's the chance of a better hand behind me?

Tags: texas-hold-em, statistics, betting-position, starting-hand

in a very casual round of poker, I'm trying to teach the others a few fundamentals about poker. I often try to back things up with some numbers, but some are too hard for me to get.

On the issue of starting hands depending on position, is there an easy way to calculate the chance of a dominating hand behind me? Like when I have A6 UTG in a game of 6 players, what's the chance that one of the other 5 has A7+ or 66+ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## There's a 23.30% chance the other players have one of {66+, A7+}.

Yes, there is an easy way to calculate the chance of a dominating hand behind you. You can use a program like [ProPokerTools Odds Oracle](http://propokertools.com/odds_oracle) to model the scenario and determine the probabilities. There is a [free trial available](http://propokertools.com/odds_oracle/trial_license_key). Below is a screenshot of the calculation as well as the log file.

[image: Calculation]

> [ProPokerTools Odds Oracle Results (2.27 Professional)](http://propokertools.com/odds_oracle)
>   Holdem, Generic syntax
>   Dead - Ac5s
>   PLAYER_2 *
>   PLAYER_3 *
>   PLAYER_4 *
>   PLAYER_5 *
>   PLAYER_6 *
>   600000 trials (randomized)
>
> ---
>
> **How often do(es) at least 1 player match hand range 66+,A7+**
>   23.2990% (139794)
>
> ---